# Outlook AddIn Add custom menu item within email

Tags: c#, vsto

I have read article about [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but 
I have not way how I can add custom menu Item in context menu within email like on picture below.[image]

Comment: I think you answer in the same link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172%28v=office.14%29.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_ContextMenuforaMailItem

Comment: @Kiru it says how to expand a context menu for everything except the body of the message if it's not then please tell me what I missed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I have found solution.

```
<contextMenus>
    <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText">      
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all context menus can be customized. Nobody knows the idMso value for the context menu shown on the screenshot.